# Create a Comb of Characters effect in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find out how to create a "Comb of Characters" effect that exists in PDF, but doing it in PHP for a standard HTML input type="text field.  This is where Text is spread across a textbox based on the max length of the textbox and the width of the textbox.

PDF definition:

Comb Of Characters
Spreads the user-entered text evenly across the width of the text field.

Lets say I had 4 digits (the amount of digits can be dynamic so 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11 etc) I wanted to spread across the following input field

```
<input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;" />
```

How would I go about doing this?  I'm sure some math is behind this, but I have no clue what the math would be.  Hoping someone has had to do this before.  Please no external libraries or anything.

***EDIT***

While RamRaider version does work using javascript/CSS I was hoping to get this in PHP.

Goal would be to have it work like

```
<input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;" value="<? echo $answer; ?>"/>
```

So an example output would be like

```
<input type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;" value="1 2 3 4"/>
```

I know I would have to manually add spaces in between each character which is where the math is very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `letter-spacing` property of css - if you were to do that in conjunction with javascript you could make it dynamic for a different number of digits in the field

```js
var div=document.getElementById('kern');
    var s=150;/* size of text field */
    var l=div.value.length;/* number of characters */
    div.style.letterSpacing=Math.ceil( s / l )+'px';
```

```css
#kern{
        letter-spacing:calc( 150px / 4 );
    }
```

```html
<input id="kern" type="text" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;" value="1234" />
```

Not wanting to admit defeat straight away the idea of using the `canvas` and it's associated methods came to mind and lead to the following - it seems to work pretty well I think.

```js
    var txt=document.getElementById('kern');
    var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctxt=canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctxt.font='12px arial';


    var s=parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( txt, null ).getPropertyValue( 'width' ) );

    txt.onchange=function(){
        ctxt.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
        var w=ctxt.measureText( this.value ).width;

        space=Math.abs( ( s - w ) / this.value.length );

        if( w < s ) this.style.letterSpacing=space+'px';
        else {
            alert('The supplied text is naturally wider than the text input field can support');
        }
    }.bind( txt );
```

```css
#kern{
        font-size:12px;
        font-family:arial;
        letter-spacing:calc( 150px / 4 );
    }
```

```html
<input id="kern" type="text" style="width:150px; height:30px;" />
```

Comment: You didn't try this with more than 4, did you ;) Calculating the precise letter spacing dynamically would be very tricky

Comment: I tried this code with 10 values and it's not working correctly, unfortunately.

Comment: having played about for 10mins in js I admit that, like @Phil said, calculating the spacing dynamically is very tricky

Comment: Yea, unfortunately, that's why I had asked Lolol.  All my thoughts and attempts had failed badly.

Comment: Just watched a video about creating combs in Acrobat - the length of the comb is defined when the field is constructed so it is relatively easy to calculate the required settings rather than a text field of arbitary length - hence the troubles trying with js now :(

Comment: What about something like this @RamRaider https://jsfiddle.net/qsywk2L7/2/ or did I get the wrong idea?

Comment: I upvoted this because it does work, but I was hoping for something in PHP not javascript/CSS.

Comment: @eqiz - You do of course realise I hope, that different browsers display the same content slightly differently. As such, an approach that doesn't take into account of any differences will work in some places and fail in others. If you can do it in plain HTML, you can do it with php. I fail to see how this is even remotely possible. Why the desire to avoid js &/or css?

Comment: its possible using imagettfbbox in php, however I just don't know the math behind it.  Because I don't need this just for displaying output on a page.  Maybe I need it to space out a string on the backend in PHP for something else like a database entry or something.  I mentioned in title I need it in PHP.  I'm trying to modify this code to work in PHP, but no succcess.

Comment: Another reason to have this capability is if someone is trying to "stamp" an image or a PDF that has a FormField that is currently set to "COMB" and want to imitate the effect as an image etc.  There is a lot of useful ways for this